# Cannot launch the Calibre ebook reader?

Tags: apt, software-installation, ebooks, calibre, epub

Why isn't `calibre` starting below?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo apt install calibre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
calibre is already the newest version (4.99.4+dfsg+really4.12.0-1build1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-51 linux-headers-5.4.0-51-generic linux-image-5.4.0-51-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-51-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-51-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 232 not upgraded.
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ calibre
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/calibre", line 20, in <module>
    sys.exit(calibre())
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui_launch.py", line 73, in calibre
    main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/main.py", line 543, in main
    listener = create_listener()
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/main.py", line 514, in create_listener
    return Listener(address=gui_socket_address())
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/utils/ipc/server.py", line 110, in __init__
    self._listener._unlink.cancel()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cancel'
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

It's always run fine in the past, although I don't recall running it from this machine on which Ubuntu was recently installed.

Comment: Calibre 5.4.2 is the current version. See https://calibre-ebook.com/whats-new and https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux

Comment: I'm not sure whether that answers the q @OrganicMarble but I'll keep looking into it.  might be the same, might not.  helpful link.

Comment: I'm using calibre (calibre 4.99.4) @heynnema  so that's the problem probably.  not sure how to get a newer version.  snap?

Comment: @NicholasSaunders the first answer in the suggested duplicate question tells one how to install a version that works on 20.04.

Comment: The second link that I gave you has all the instructions on how to install the newer version. Uninstall the 4.99 version first. Then install 5.4.2.

Comment: yeh, mighta screwed it up.  anyhow, the flatpak version runs from the GUI fine.  I don't seem to have `calibre` on the path, but that's okay for now.  duplicate I guess.  Flagged it just now.