# how to launch flatpak calibre from the console?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, flatpak, ebooks, calibre

How do I start `calibre` from the `bash` console?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ com.calibre_ebook.calibre
com.calibre_ebook.calibre: command not found
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ calibre

Command 'calibre' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install calibre

nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ flatpak list
Name                                         Application ID                            Version        Branch      Installation
Calibre                                      com.calibre_ebook.calibre                 5.4.2          stable      system
Freedesktop Platform                         org.freedesktop.Platform                  20.08.1.2      20.08       system
default                                      org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default                      19.08       system
default                                      org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default                      20.08       system
Intel                                        org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel                     19.08       system
Intel                                        org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel                     20.08       system
openh264                                     org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264         2.1.0          2.0         system
FeedReader                                   org.gnome.FeedReader                      2.11.0         stable      system
GNOME Application Platform version 3.36      org.gnome.Platform                                       3.36        system
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Here, `calibre` was [installed](https://askubuntu.com/q/1291546/847449) from `flatpak` as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run any installed flatpak using `flatpak run`, by providing the flatpak REF.

```shell
flatpak run com.calibre_ebook.calibre
```

More information is available with `flatpak run --help` [or `man flatpak-run`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/flatpak-run.1.html)