# How to run or execute the ebook-convert script from a flatpak install of calibre?

Tags: command-line, manpage, flatpak, ebooks, calibre

Where and how can I run the `ebook-convert` script for calibre **from the console**?

```
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ flatpak info com.calibre_ebook.calibre

calibre - The one stop solution to all your e-book needs

          ID: com.calibre_ebook.calibre
         Ref: app/com.calibre_ebook.calibre/x86_64/stable
        Arch: x86_64
      Branch: stable
     Version: 5.23.0
     License: GPL-3.0
      Origin: flathub
  Collection: org.flathub.Stable
Installation: system
   Installed: 360.9 MB
     Runtime: org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/20.08
         Sdk: org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/20.08

      Commit: 13464e660f35716a725261af4b45d3abc199a3ce52ebdd9ee887c7ae623b5873
      Parent: 4f7f3b603f31cc781caf8260f887118a1bb466748891c9e122826728e25d3eed
     Subject: Update calibre-5.22.1-x86_64.txz to 5.23.0 (9184a3f3)
        Date: 2021-07-11 19:56:21 +0000
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ uname -a
Linux gondor 5.8.0-59-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 00:46:01 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ man calibre
No manual entry for calibre
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ ebook-convert
Command 'ebook-convert' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install calibre
nicholas@gondor:~$
```

Installed via flatpak because:

1.)  calibre is, or at least wasn't, in `snap` repo
2.)  have had problems with the `apt` version in the past

more of a flatpak usage q than specific to Ubuntu.  Probably a `calibre` or `flatpak` man page will explain where or how to launch the conversion script -- but which man page?

tried:

```
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ flatpak run com.calibre_ebook.calibre.ebook-convert
error: app/com.calibre_ebook.calibre.ebook-convert/x86_64/master not installed
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ flatpak run com.calibre_ebook.ebook-convert
error: app/com.calibre_ebook.ebook-convert/x86_64/master not installed
nicholas@gondor:~$
```

see also

[how to launch flatpak calibre from the console?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1314813/847449)

Answer (score 4):

According to [Debugging section of Flatpak guide](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/debugging.html) and [`man flatpak-run`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/flatpak-run.1.html) you can use special `--command` argument.

So we need to enter the shell by

```
flatpak --command="sh" run com.calibre_ebook.calibre
```

and then run conversion here:

> ```
> [ com.calibre_ebook.calibre ~]$ ebook-convert in.epub out.fb2
> 1% Converting input to HTML...
> InputFormatPlugin: EPUB Input running
> on /home/user/in.epub
> ...
> Converting XHTML to FB2 markup...
> FB2 output written to /home/user/out.fb2
> Output saved to   /home/user/out.fb2
> [ com.calibre_ebook.calibre ~]$ exit
> $ ls in.epub out.fb2
> in.epub  out.fb2
> ```

Or more straight-forward:

```
flatpak --command="sh" run com.calibre_ebook.calibre \
-c "ebook-convert ~/in.epub ~/out.fb2"
```

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the answer of [@N0rbert](https://askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert), you need to use the `--command` switch which allows you to execute the `ebook-convert` script:

```bsh
flatpak --command="ebook-convert" run com.calibre_ebook.calibre input.epub output.epub
```

For simplified usage and compatibility with scripting you can create an executable script named `ebook-convert` and place it in `~/.local/bin`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

flatpak --command="ebook-convert" run com.calibre_ebook.calibre "${1}" "${2}"
```

Then you can simply use `ebook-convert input.epub output.epub` from the command line or from a user script.

Comment: Or make an alias: `alias ebook-convert='flatpak --command="ebook-convert" run com.calibre_ebook.calibre'"`

Comment: @red_trumpet The alias is great for manual conversion but won't help if the conversion needs to be triggered by a script.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how flatpak works, but I was able to find the script like this:

```
$ which calibre
/usr/bin/calibre
$ ls -artl /usr/bin/calibre
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Jul  2 20:18 /usr/bin/calibre -> /opt/calibre/calibre
$ cd /opt/calibre
ls -artl ebook-convert
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6400 Jun 25 14:54 ebook-convert
```