# flatpak calibre: Cannot read from /home/nicholas/in.epub (permissions?)

Tags: command-line, convert, flatpak, ebooks, calibre

Looking to [convert](https://askubuntu.com/q/1352523/847449) an `epub` to `mobi` with `calibre`:

```
nicholas@gondor:~/ebooks$ 
nicholas@gondor:~/ebooks$ flatpak --command="sh" run com.calibre_ebook.calibre -c "ebook-convert ~/in.epub ~/out.mobi"
Cannot read from /home/nicholas/in.epub
nicholas@gondor:~/ebooks$ 
nicholas@gondor:~/ebooks$ ll
total 1200
drwxrwxr-x  2 nicholas nicholas    4096 Jul 18 13:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 28 nicholas nicholas    4096 Jul 18 13:16 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 nicholas nicholas 1220236 Jul 18 13:16 in.epub
nicholas@gondor:~/ebooks$ 
nicholas@gondor:~/ebooks$ uname -a
Linux gondor 5.8.0-59-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 00:46:01 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
nicholas@gondor:~/ebooks$ 
nicholas@gondor:~/ebooks$ flatpak info com.calibre_ebook.calibre

calibre - The one stop solution to all your e-book needs

          ID: com.calibre_ebook.calibre
         Ref: app/com.calibre_ebook.calibre/x86_64/stable
        Arch: x86_64
      Branch: stable
     Version: 5.23.0
     License: GPL-3.0
      Origin: flathub
  Collection: org.flathub.Stable
Installation: system
   Installed: 360.9 MB
     Runtime: org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/20.08
         Sdk: org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/20.08

      Commit: 13464e660f35716a725261af4b45d3abc199a3ce52ebdd9ee887c7ae623b5873
      Parent: 4f7f3b603f31cc781caf8260f887118a1bb466748891c9e122826728e25d3eed
     Subject: Update calibre-5.22.1-x86_64.txz to 5.23.0 (9184a3f3)
        Date: 2021-07-11 19:56:21 +0000
nicholas@gondor:~/ebooks$
```

The file was readable and converted to `mobi` fine with an [online](https://ebook.online-convert.com/convert-to-mobi) converter.  The converted file loaded on a Kindle fine, so there's presumably no problem with the `epub` itself.  The book is readable on the Kindle, converted fine.

How is this accomplished from the console using the flatpak install of `calibre`?

---

note:  the GUI for `calibre` reads from the home directory fine and adds books to its library.  This book is, in fact, in the `calibre` library.  The scope of the question is just how to use the conversion script for the flatpak install of `calibre`.

There's nothing odd or unique about permissions to directories, it's a vanilla install.  Presumably some flatpak weirdness.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong paths in command line.
The `~/in.epub` and `~/ebooks/in.epub` are different paths.

So you have to use correct paths:

```
flatpak --command="sh" run com.calibre_ebook.calibre -c "ebook-convert ~/ebooks/in.epub ~/ebooks/out.mobi"
```

or

```
cd ~/ebooks
flatpak --command="sh" run com.calibre_ebook.calibre -c "ebook-convert in.epub out.mobi"
```